# Ruby Watir: cannot launch browser in a thread in Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, watir

I'm trying to run this code in Red Hat Linux, and it won't launch a browser.  The only way I can get it to work is if i ALSO launch a browser OUTSIDE of the thread, which makes no sense to me.  Here is what I mean:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"]
$alphabet.each do |z|
    puts "pshaw"
    Thread.new{
        Thread.current["testPuts"] =  "ohai " + z.to_s
        Thread.current["myBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff
        puts Thread.current["testPuts"]     }

    $browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
end
```

the output is:

```
pshaw
(launches browser)
ohai A
(launches browser)
pshaw
(launches browser)
ohai B
(launches browser)
pshaw
(launches browser)
ohai C
(launches browser)
```

However, if I remove the browser launch that is outside of the thread, as so:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"]

    $alphabet.each do |z|
puts "pshaw"
Thread.new{
    Thread.current["testPuts"] =  "ohai " + z.to_s
    Thread.current["myBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff
    puts Thread.current["testPuts"]     }
end
```

The output is:

```
pshaw
pshaw
pshaw
```

What is going on here?  How do I fix this so that I can launch a browser inside a thread?

EDIT TO ADD:

The solution Justin Ko provided worked on the psedocode above, but it's not helping with my actual code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require_relative 'Credentials'
require_relative 'ReportGenerator'
require_relative 'installPageLayouts'
require_relative 'PackageHandler'
Dir[(Dir.pwd.to_s + "/bmx*")].each {|file| require_relative file } #this includes all the files in the directory with names starting with bmx


module Runner
def self.runTestCases(orgType, *caseNumbers)
    $testCaseArray = Array.new

    caseNumbers.each do |thisCaseNum|
        $testCaseArray << thisCaseNum
    end

    $allTestCaseResults = Array.new
    $alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"]
    @count = 0
    @multiOrg = 0
    @peOrg = 0
    @eeOrg = 0
    @threads = Array.new
    $testCaseArray.each do |thisCase|
        $alphabet[@count] = Thread.new {    
            puts "working one"
            Thread.current["tBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff
            puts "working two"
            if ((thisCase.declareOrg().downcase == "multicurrency") || (thisCase.declareOrg().downcase == "mc"))
                currentOrg = $multicurrencyOrgArray[@multiOrg]
                @multiOrg += 1
            elsif ((thisCase.declareOrg().downcase == "enterprise") || (thisCase.declareOrg().downcase == "ee"))
                currentOrg = $eeOrgArray[@eeOrg]
                @eeOrg += 1         
            else #default to single currency PE
                currentOrg = $peOrgArray[@peOrg]
                @peOrg += 1
            end
            setupOrg(currentOrg, thisCase.testCaseID, currentOrg.layoutDirectory)
            runningTest = thisCase.actualTest()
            if runningTest.crashed != "crashed" #changed this to read the attr_reader isntead of the deleted caseStatus method from TestCase.rb
                cleanupOrg(thisCase.testCaseID, currentOrg.layoutDirectory)
            end
                        @threads << Thread.current
        }
        @count += 1     
    end 

    @threads.each do |thisThread|           
        thisThread.join
    end
    writeReport($allTestCaseResults)
end



def self.setupOrg(thisOrg, caseID, layoutPath)
    begin
        thisOrg.logIn
        pkg = PackageHandler.new
        basicInstalled = "false"
        counter = 0
        until ((basicInstalled == "true") || (counter == 5))
            pkg.basicInstaller()
            if Thread.current["tBrowser"].text.include? "You have attempted to access a page"
                thisOrg.logIn
            else    
                basicInstalled = "true"
            end
            counter +=1
        end
        if !((caseID.include? "bmxb") || (caseID.include? "BMXB"))
            moduleInstalled = "false"
            counter2 = 0
            until ((moduleInstalled == "true") || (counter == 5))
                pkg.packageInstaller(caseID)
                if Thread.current["tBrowser"].text.include? "You have attempted to access a page"
                    thisOrg.logIn
                else    
                    moduleInstalled = "true"
                end
                counter2 +=1
            end 
        end
        installPageLayouts(layoutPath)
    rescue
        $allTestCaseResults << TestCaseResult.new(caseID, caseID, 1, "SETUP FAILED!" + "<p>#{$!}</p><p>#{$@}</p>").hashEmUp
        writeReport($allTestCaseResults)
    end
end

def self.cleanupOrg(caseID, layoutPath)
    begin
        uninstallPageLayouts(layoutPath)
        pkg = PackageHandler.new
        pkg.packageUninstaller(caseID)
        Thread.current["tBrowser"].close
    rescue
        $allTestCaseResults << TestCaseResult.new(caseID, caseID, 1, "CLEANUP FAILED!" + "<p>#{$!}</p><p>#{$@}</p>").hashEmUp
        writeReport($allTestCaseResults)
    end
end



end
```

The output it's generating is:

```
working one
working one
working one
```

It's not opening a browser or doing any of the subsequent code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the code is having the problem mentioned in the [Thread class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html):

> If we don't call thr.join before the main thread terminates, then all
>   other threads including thr will be killed.

Basically your main thread is finishing pretty instantaneously. However, the threads, which create browsers, take a lot longer than that. As result the threads get terminated before the browser opens.

By adding a long sleep at the end, you can see that your browsers can be opened by your code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$chunkythread = ["A", "B", "C"]
$chunkythread.each do |z|
  puts "pshaw"
  Thread.new{
    Thread.current["testwords"] =  "ohai " + z.to_s
    Thread.current["myBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff
    puts Thread.current["testwords"]    }
end
sleep(300)
```

However, for more reliability, you should join all the threads at the end:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
threads = []
$chunkythread = ["A", "B", "C"]
$chunkythread.each do |z|
  puts "pshaw"
  threads << Thread.new{
    Thread.current["testwords"] =  "ohai " + z.to_s
    Thread.current["myBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff
    puts Thread.current["testwords"]    }
end
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

For the actual code example, putting `@threads << Thread.current` will not work. The join will be evaluating like `@threads` is empty. You could try doing the following:

```
$testCaseArray.each do |thisCase|
    @threads << Thread.new {    
        puts "working one"
        Thread.current["tBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :ff

        # Do your other thread stuff
    }
    $alphabet[@count] = @threads.last
    @count += 1     
end 

@threads.each do |thisThread|           
    thisThread.join
end
```

Note that I am not sure why you want to store the threads in `$alphabet`. I put in the `$alphabet[@count] = @threads.last`, but could be removed if not in use.

Comment: Thank you, Justin!  I tried that, and it made the code I was testing with work perfectly.  The problem now is that I already had a thread.join on my actual (way more complicated) code, and it's doing the behavior I initially posted here about.  Would it help if I put that code up?

Comment: Yes, if you have a more complicated example that shows your problem, it would help to see that.

Comment: Added to my original post

Comment: Is there more to your actual code? It seems a bit weird that `@threads` is not defined anywhere, but you are joining its threads. As well, the thread you assign to `$alphabet[@count]` never gets joined (which is likely your problem).

Comment: Yes, there is.  I added it.  I left it off at first because I figured I had to draw the line somewhere.  This is part of a package of code that's probably somewhere between 2000 and 3000 lines.  It works fine in Windows but is acting how I've described in Linux.

Comment: I tried adding $alphabet[@count].join on the line before count+=1, and that resulted in a "stack level too deep" error on that line.

Comment: I don't actually need the $alphabet array.  It was i there for debugging.  When I have it in there, the output displays the initial "puts" in the thread and runs the writeReport method.  When I just do @threads << Thread.new, I get a "stack level too deep" on thisThread.join without anything else happening.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Watir 5.0.0 and installed Watir 4.0.2, and now it works fine.